# Is it not allowed create a static library without a .c file in it?

Tags: gcc, static-libraries, unix-ar

I have two files -> `fact.h` and `main.c` in the `/home/snyp1/new` folder. `main.c` has the main function which calls the `fact(int x)` function in `fact.h`. I am creating a `.a` archive with the ar command ->

```
snyp1@Snyp:~/new$ ar -r -s libfact.a fact.o
ar: creating libfact.a
fact.h  fact.o  libfact.a  main.c
snyp1@Snyp:~/new$ gcc main.c -L/home/snyp1/new -lfact -o main
/home/snyp1/new/libfact.a: could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
snyp1@Snyp:~/new$ ranlib libfact.a
snyp1@Snyp:~/new$ gcc main.c -L/home/snyp1/new -lfact -o main
/home/snyp1/new/libfact.a: could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am on ubuntu 12.04. Please let me know whats wrong. (Also, if I don't use the `-L/.../new`, gcc will say it can't find "lfact", maybe its because its not in `/usr/local/lib`)

EDIT: OK I have found the cause. Its due to the fact that I was using `fact.h` to build the `fact.o` and then putting it in the library, it wasn't working as expected. So I now changed it into `file.c` and is working fine now. I should have provided that information, I'm sorry. Though I don't know why this kind of problem should arise. Aren't libraries possible to make without at least one `.c` file in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was using fact.h to build the fact.o and then putting it in the library, it wasn't working as expected.

Do you mean you were compiling `fact.h` to produce `fact.o`?

If so, that wasn't doing what you expect. When you invoke `gcc` on a header file it produces a precompiled header, **not** an object file. So although you got a file called `foo.o` it wasn't a valid object file. If you had just run `gcc -c fact.h` it would have produced a precompiled header `fact.gch`, but presumably you ran `gcc -c fact.h -o fact.o` which causes the file to be called `fact.o` even though it's still a precompiled header.  `file fact.o` would have shown that:

```
$ file fact.o
fact.o: GCC precompiled header (version 013) for C
```

You could have forced GCC to treat the file as C code, not a header, by running `gcc -x c -c fact.h -o fact.o` (the `-x c` says to treat the input as C code instead of inferring the type from the file extension) but it's probably simpler and less confusing to just name your file correctly instead of trying to compile a header.

> Aren't libraries possible to make without at least one .c file in it?

They need at least one object file (i.e. `.o` file) but you didn't have a valid object, you had a precompiled header misleadingly named as `.o`, but it was not actually an object file.

> if I don't use the `-L/.../new`, gcc will say it can't find "lfact", maybe its because its not in `/usr/local/lib`

The linker doesn't only look in `/usr/local/lib`, there are other default places it looks, but yes, that's basically the problem. Note that you can also say `-L.` if the library is in the current directory, that's easier than giving an absolute path.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I had the function body inside the header file, which works fine if I do $gcc main.c -o main , I didn't know about header files are converted into a precompiled header.

Comment: Indeed, a well-designed header file contains only interface, not implementation, so if you did compile it to `.o` it would be empty.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure `ar` supports a dash on anything other than the first option. Try

```
ar -rs libfact.a fact.o
```

or just

```
ar rs libfact.a fact.o
```

Mind you, I don't know why running `ranlib` didn't work though.

Comment: Correct, the official usage is: `ar [-]p[mod] archive [member...]` where the dash is optional, `p` is the operation to perform (in this case `r`) and `mod` is zero or more modifiers (in this case `s`) so it should be `ar rs` or `ar -rs`

Comment: `ar -r -s` is legal POSIX syntax, as a result of the [Utility Syntax Guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) which are slowly eroding the traditional unix syntaxes.